# Extra Vertical line at the end of the long table

Tags: tables, longtable

I am using share latex and trying to create a long table. When I generated the 
 long table an extra vertical row is created at the end visible in the attached image. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.[image: Verticl line missing at the end and]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}




\begin{document}



\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}| p{4cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \caption{Features used by Bebei}\\

    \hline
    \textbf{ index}& \textbf{Features name}  & \textbf{Explanation}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \tabularnewline
    \hline
   \textbf{ index}& \textbf{Features name}  & \textbf{Explanation}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        %\hline



    \label{tab:bebeifeatures}
\end{longtable}


       \end{document}
```

Comment: it's the `\label` making an empty cell stick it in another cell or in the argument to caption or pretty much anywhere other than where it is:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, You are right  label is the culprit. Thanks for your help. I might have to find other way to refer the table.

Comment: why do you need another way to refer to the table? you can use `\label` just place it in an existing cell not a new cell on its own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP says it's been solved in comments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You should convert that to an answer

Comment: I am unable to attach the solution as the question is on Hold

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the answer has been reopened, if you would like to add an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by David Carlisle `\label` was creating the extra vertical line. The solution is to add the `\label` to an existing cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}    
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}| p{4cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \caption{Features used by Bebei}\\

    \hline
    \textbf{ index}& \textbf{Features name}  & \textbf{Explanation}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \tabularnewline
    \hline
   \textbf{ index}& \textbf{Features name}  & \textbf{Explanation}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for testing\\
        \hline
        1 & Number of objects & This is supposed to be the  largest sentence i am using for \label{tab:bebeifeatures}\\
        \hline
        %\hline


\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```